# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property [id] not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-el

I work with Spring boot project and I get the following error while I run the app,

```
2017-10-03 22:10:36.726 ERROR 978 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter     : Forwarding to error page from request [/users] due to exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page [/WEB-INF/jsp/list.jsp] at line [44]

41: 
42:         <tbody>
43:         <c:forEach var="user" items="{users}">
44:             <tr><c:out value="${user.id}"/></tr>
45:             <tr><c:out value="${user.name}"/></tr>
46:             <tr><c:out value="${user.email}"/></tr>
47:         </c:forEach>

.........

.........
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property [id] not found on type [java.lang.String]
```

The user class I have,

```
@Entity
public class User {

    // form:hidden - hidden value
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // form:input - textbox
    @Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(30)", nullable = false)
    String name;

    // form:input - textbox
    @Column(name = "email", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50)", nullable = false)
    String email;

    // form:input - password
    @Column(name = "password", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(20)", nullable = false)
    String password;

    // form:textarea - textarea
    @Column(name = "address", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)")
    String address;

    // form:input - password
    @Transient
    String confirmPassword;

    // form:checkbox - single checkbox
    @Column(name = "newsletter")
    boolean newsletter;

    // form:radiobutton - radio button
    @Column(name = "sex", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(1)")
    String sex;

    // form:radiobuttons - radio button
    @Column(name = "number")
    Integer number;

    // form:select - form:option - dropdown - single select
    @Column(name = "country", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(10)")
    String country;

    // form:checkboxes - multiple checkboxes
    @ElementCollection
//    @Column(name = "framework", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(500)")
    List<String> framework;

    // form:select - multiple=true - dropdown - multiple select
    @ElementCollection
//    @Column(name = "skill", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(500)")
    List<String> skill;
}
```

The user controller class is provided,

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    private static List<User> populateDefaultUserValues() {

        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Ella");
        user.setEmail("xyz@gmail.com");
        user.setPassword("df32d343H");
        user.setFramework(Arrays.asList("Spring MVC, GWT".split("\\s*,\\s*")));
        users.add(user);


        user = new User();
        user.setName("Alex");
        user.setEmail("alex@hotmail.com");
        user.setPassword("12HH2d343H");
        user.setFramework(Arrays.asList("Spring MVC, GWT".split("\\s*,\\s*")));
        users.add(user);


        user = new User();
        user.setName("KKomanna");
        user.setEmail("romanna@hotmail.com");
        user.setPassword("Rommann343");
        user.setFramework(Arrays.asList("Spring MVC, GWT".split("\\s*,\\s*")));
        users.add(user);

        return users;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "redirect:/users";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/users")
    public String showAllUsers(Model model) {

        List<User> users = populateDefaultUserValues();

        users.forEach(user -> {
            userService.save(user);
        });

//        System.out.println("/n/n/n/n" + (userService.findAll()).stream().map(Object::toString)
//                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) + "/n/n/n/n");

        model.addAttribute("users", userService.findAll());
        return "list";
    }
}
```

I have the feeling the `userService.findAll()` returns the `List<String>` instead of the `List<User>`. Some experiment, I happen to know that the `<c:out value="${users}"/>` will return an array of 3 elements (I guess name, email, and password)

I also plan to access the frameworks value like,

```
               `<td><c:forEach var="framework" items="${user.framework}" varStatus="loop">
                    ${framework}
                    <c:if test="${not loop.last}">,</c:if>
                    </c:forEach></td>
                <td>`
```

The app created 3 tables in the MySQL database namely `user`, `user_framework` and `user_skill` and have the following values,

[image]

[image]

and,

[image]

I would like to populate the JSP with the code,

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${users}">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        ${user.id}
                    </td>
                    <td>${user.name}</td>
                    <td>${user.email}</td>
                    <td><c:forEach var="framework" items="${user.framework}" varStatus="loop">
                        ${framework}
                        <c:if test="${not loop.last}">,</c:if>
                        </c:forEach></td>
                    <td>
                   </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

The interface and the implementation of the `service` directory is provided,

```
public interface UserService {

    List<User> findAll();

    User findById(Long idx);

    void save(User user);

    void delete(Long idx);
}
```

The implementation is here,

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return (List)userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public User findById(Long idx) {
        return userRepository.findOne(idx);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long idx) {
        userRepository.delete(idx);
    }
}
```

How do I solve the error and populate the JSP properly?

Comment: Did you try using user_id instead of id?

Comment: do you mean like `${user.user_id}`? Tied by now, it doesn't help though

Comment: @AAA If you remove the column from jsp for user.id what’s the behaviour? Is it still complain for other fields of user?

Comment: This provides the error for all `${user.column_values}`

Comment: How do you fetch the `{users}` in `<c:forEach var="user" items="{users}">`? I guess your assumption is correct, the error is telling that `{users}` is `List<String>` instead of `List<User>`

Comment: What do you mean by how do I fetch? I'm more or less certain that it comes as `List<String>` though I dont know how to solve the issue

Comment: @AAA your UserService is custom repository declared? Or it is just using the spring boot starter concept of mentioning? Check the findAll signature in case it is customized

Comment: @AAA Also add the user repository code and try to remove the explicit casting to only collection holder list

Comment: @AAA You said you had the feeling that `userService.findAll()` return a list of String but you did not post the method, unless you can't

Comment: @Al1 I have provided the interface and implementation of the service directory in the updated question. Those are simple and though not required to get a solution

Comment: Well this is clearly wrong: `items="{users}"`

Comment: @AlanHay this indeed solves the issue. I apologize for not concentrating, perhaps it's better to delete the question. What do you say?

Comment: @AAA or can Your service method findAll be like {return (List<User>) userRepository.findAll()}

Comment: @AAA if your issue is solved, I would suggest to post a short self answer. It may help other who fell into the same trap

Comment: I will do in the morning then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, I made a silly mistake in due to the loss of concentration. For looping a list that comes from the Spring controller, you need to put a `$` sign precedently and then to loop through it. The code sample would be,

```
          <c:forEach var="user" items="${users}">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        ${user.id}
                    </td>
                    <td>${user.name}</td>
                    <td>${user.email}</td>
                    <td><c:forEach var="framework" items="${user.framework}" varStatus="loop">
                        ${framework}
                        <c:if test="${not loop.last}">,</c:if>
                        </c:forEach></td>
                    <td>
                   </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```